# Can't Start Python On Windows Machine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm seeing this message.

[image]

My version of Python 3.6 worked fine yesterday.  Not sure what happened, but I lost my access to my Python.  :(

Anyone here have any thoughts on how to fix this?  Maybe there is a command to run to reset everything???

Comment: Um... What's that if not Python?!

Comment: The interpreter looks fine from your screenshot. Are you concerned about the Warning? Use conda to activate your virtualenv before you run python and the Warning will go away. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

Answer (score 2):

Go to: https://conda.io/activation to activate the environment then the warning will go away. It seems as if python works for you even through the warning is displayed.

Comment: Hey there Daniel.  That link doesn't work.  And, skullgoblet1089, I tried your suggestion and that didn't work either.  There should be a way to do a master reset, I think.

Comment: looks like the link has been misspelt.  it should be [https://conda.io/activation](https://conda.io/activation)

Comment: It turned out to be a couple things.  Open the command prompt and type 'spyder' to see what the issue is.  Then try a few things.  Enter 'Reset Spyder Settings' in the Windows search button.  Click the app and a black screen pops open and resets spyder.  Or, if that doesn't work, in the command prompt type 'pip install -U spyder'.  When it finishes running, run spyder.  The combination of those things worked for me.